# Suppose the sequence $(X_n)$ converges to $x$, and $\lim(Y_n −X_n) =0$. Show $Y_n$ also converges to $x$

Tags: analysis

my answer was 
$$Y_n-X_n=0 \implies |Y_n-X_n| < \epsilon \implies$$
$$|Y_n-x+x-X_n| < \epsilon \implies |Y_n-x|+|x-X_n|<\epsilon,(|x-X_n|=|X_n-x|=0)$$
$\implies|Y_n-x|<\epsilon \implies \lim_{n\to\infty} (Y_n)=x$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** Note that
$$|Y_n-x| \leq |Y_n-X_n|+|X_n-x| \qquad \forall n,$$
and apply the definitions.

**Hint2**

> Let $\epsilon >0$, since $\lim_{n\to \infty} Y_n-X_n = 0$ and $\lim_{n\to \infty} X_n = x$, there is $N_1$ and $N_2$ such that
>  $$|X_n-Y_n|<\frac{\epsilon}{2} \quad \forall n > N_1 \quad \text{ and } \quad |X_n-x|< \frac{\epsilon}{2} \quad \forall n > N_2.$$

Comment: Your proof doesn't work because $\lim_{n\to\infty} X_n-Y_n$ does not imply $X_n-Y_n=0$ for every $n$. E.g. $X_n = \frac{2}{n}, Y_n = \frac{1}{n}$

Comment: i used Yn -Xn and not Xn-Yn  and it was given that Yn-Xn=0

Comment: By definition, I mean: "$\lim_{n\to\infty} Z_n = z$" $\ \iff \ \forall \epsilon >0, \exists N \in \Bbb N$ s.t. $|Z_n-z|< \epsilon, \forall n >N$.

Comment: @AxelFoley this doesn't make any difference, $\lim_{n \to \infty} Y_n-X_n = 0 \iff \lim_{n \to \infty} X_n-Y_n = 0$. Anyway, my counter example still works.

Comment: can i let Yn-Xn =ε/2 and Xn-x=ε/2 and get Yn-x<ε  ?

Comment: @AxelFoley Exactly! :) (I was writing it as a second hint ;))